# Partial name Object is not a valid Ruby identifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am rendering a partial as part of my Ajax call and am getting an error

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (The partial name (94.0) is not a valid Ruby identifier; make sure your partial name starts with underscore, and is followed by any combination of letters, numbers and underscores.):
```

I haven't seen this before and am not sure how it is being generated. In this case 94 is the returned value of @subtotal

I was also hoping someone could clarify how the partial is rendered (i.e naming convention of views) when i do

```
<%= j render partial: @object %>
```

So in my case I have a section that holds the Subtotal of items in a users shopping cart

```
class CartItemsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @subtotal = CartItem.subtotal
  end

  def destroy
    @cart_item = CartItem.find(params[:id])
    @cart_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart_item.destroy
        @subtotal = CartItem.subtotal
        format.js { flash.now[:success] = 'Successfully removed from cart'  }
      else
        format.js { flash.now[:error] = 'Sorry, Something went wrong' }
      end
  end
end
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$("#cart-subtotal").empty().append('<%= j render partial: @subtotal %>');
```

The name of my partial is _subtotal.html.erb, located at `/views/subtotal/_subtotal.html.erb`

Can anybody see if i have done anything wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: The message says it all. The name for the partial file should start with an underscore(_).

Comment: Iv'e updated my question with my partial name

Comment: Try `"<%= j render partial: 'subtotal/subtotal' %>"`

Comment: I think here `$("#cart-subtotal").empty().append('<%= j render partial: @subtotal %>');` you should use `render partial: 'subtotal'`

Comment: that's worked (and had to move my partial to `views/cart_items/_subtotal.html.erb`), my question is now why did that work? thank you

Comment: It worked because before you were passing an instance variable as an argument to `render partial`, but it awaits for a string name of the partial, that is in the directory of the same name as controller's name (otherwise it would expect the relative path to partial)

Comment: You can keep the location as `/views/subtotal/_subtotal.html.erb` and change it to `"<%= j render partial: 'subtotal/subtotal' %>"`

Comment: There is a ```to_partial_path``` method that helps to determine what partial should be rendered when you use ```render @object```

Comment: Thanks for your help guys....You will notice i am declaring `@subtotal` in two actions, show and destroy.... is there a better way to handle this, feels like im repeating myself that's all

Comment: You can use a filter for that.

Comment: like a before_filter ?

Comment: Yes. like a before_filter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ActionView::Template::Error (The partial name (94.0) is not a valid
>   Ruby identifier; make sure your partial name starts with underscore,
>   and is followed by any combination of letters, numbers and
>   underscores.)

The problem is here `'<%= j render partial: @subtotal %>'`. `@subtotal` holds the value of `CartItem.subtotal` which is ***94.0***. When you are rendering a partial, you should specify the ***name of the partial*** which in your case should be ***subtotal***. And since the location of the partial is in `/views/subtotal`, it should be `"<%= j render partial: 'subtotal/subtotal' %>"`

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
("#cart-subtotal").empty().append('<%= j render partial: @subtotal %>');
```

you are passing the `@subtotal` object as an argument to `render partial:`, but it expects a string name of the partial.

Two options:

1) move the partial to `cart_items` folder and

```
$("#cart-subtotal").empty().append('<%= j render partial: 'subtotal' %>');
```

2) leave the partial where it is and

```
$("#cart-subtotal").empty().append('<%= j render partial: 'subtotal/subtotal' %>');
```

Regarding variable @subtotal:

```
before_action :subtotal, only: %i(show destroy)

private

def subtotal
  @subtotal ||= CartItem.subtotal
end
```

Thus you will have `@subtotal` variable DRY.

Comment: Thanks @AndreyDeineko that helps a lot :-)